# Hexadecimal unicode in c with printf()

Tags: c, gcc, printf

this is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    printf("%x\n",*argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

after compile `(gcc -o main main.c)` , i run it and with no problem:

```
./main 1
31
```

note:`31` is hex code of `1`

but when run it with `Unicode` parameter, print `4Byte` of hex:

```
./main $(printf "\Udbb1")
ffffffed
```

what is problem?

Comment: `%x` means `int`, but you're passing a `char` value.

Comment: If you expected it to print `dbb1`, you're in for a fun time reading about Unicode encodings, and (most probably) UTF-8. A single `char` on most modern computers won't be able to hold `0xdbb1`, since it's typically only 8 bits wide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things at play here:

The first is that when you pass an argument to a variable-argument function like `printf` it might be [*promoted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions). What happens here is that the character is [promoted to an `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) value.

And here the other thing comes in, namely *sign extension*. If you convert a small signed type (like `char` seems to be on your system) to another larger signed type (like `int`), if the smaller type is negative then the larger type has to be the same negative number. And because of the way [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (which is the most common to handle negative numbers on binary systems) works the value will be filled up with leading binary ones.

If you want to print only the `char` value you need to use the [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format prefix `hh` as in `"%hhx"`. The value will then be treated as an `unsigned char`.